# Shower divider wall – load bearing?

Tags: walls, load

Redoing the shower in the master bathroom on 2nd floor and debating whether to knock out a wall and put in a corner glass enclosure. Started by removing framing to make 7’ shower to an 8’ shower. Easy enough. Now I need to know whether the small divider wall is a bearing wall. Here are the facts:

-house has roof truss construction that spans end to end (no rafters, etc.). House built 1991. Many lofted ceilings, open areas, etc. I am thinking the exterior walls only support the loads.

-to further that, neighboring space in hallway (see pictures) is open end to end, meaning there is unsupported open space that runs end to end of the house (no walls for support). End to end measures 23,8”.

-wall is 34” long and is 3’2” away from one exterior side. You can see the exterior window in 1 of the pictures. Point being is that this isn’t a wall in middle of the house. There is just the toilet between it and the exterior wall.

-The bottom of 1 truss is in contact with the top of the wall. All the other stuff is furring strips for attaching ceiling drywall, etc. There is a double top plate, but like others have said, this may not mean anything. The wall on the other side of the shower is single top plate (this wall with the plumbing is staying). Not sure why.

-I have steel support posts in the middle of the basement which are more toward the center of the house. None of the walls seem to be aligned with them – they are in different spots. The wall in question is toward the front of the house (3’2” away), not in the center area (11-12 feet).
I am thinking it can’t be load bearing. Was looking up structural engineers, but everything in the township is shut down due to COVID, except for emergencies. Is this cut and dry enough where I probably don’t have to worry? I am a mechanical engineer, but do product design, so residential construction isn’t exactly my specialty. Thoughts?
[image: Shower wall]

[image: House interior]
[image: Other wall]

[image: Roof trusses]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trusses are self-supporting.  So if what you're showing in the first photo is indeed the bottom span of a truss, and it's supported on both ends, then no, that is not a load bearing wall.

If there is any doubt, however, please consult with a structural engineer.